# How t o install Pandas into the raspberry pi?

Tags: pip, shared-libraries

I'am trying to install pandas using `pip install pandas` and I get the following error

`Exception: Cython-generated file 'pandas/io/sas/sas.c' not found.
                    Cython is required to compile pandas from a development branch.
                    Please install Cython or download a release package of pandas.`

`Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-bDbkpJ/pandas/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-J1gUG5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-bDbkpJ/pandas/`

Further I tried with `sudo apt-get install python-pandas` , which installed the pandas packages.

Comment: Try installing it with _sudo_ first. If you are installing in python3, use _pip3_. And to use any specific version, you can use a command like _sudo pip3 install pandas==1.0.3_.

Comment: "*... sudo apt-get ... which installed the pandas packages.*" So what's the problem? Doesn't it work?

Comment: try `pip3 install pandas`